# jenkins credential api plugin to update all passwords

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I just started using jenkins and I have many projects that have passwords. I need to change them multiple times a year but I do not want to go and manually do it each time. I read that the credential api plugin allows the user to update one password and it will change the rest but I am unclear how to do this.